# Abrir PDF desde un Listview con el metodo setOnItemClickListener

Tags: pdf, android-fragment, listview, activity, onclick

Tengo una Listview en un fragmento llamado "CoritarioFragment.java", con su respectivo adaptador. La idea es que al hacer click en cada elemento de la lista, me lleve a una pagina especifica de un PDF (el cual ya tengo añadido y anda bien).
El problema es que no logro pasar los datos con el metodo putExtra al activity del PDF para que cargue la pagina que quiero y cuando hago click en un elemento se me cierra la aplicacion.
Ya probe sacando el metodo putExtra y el PDF abre correctamente pero no en la pagina que quiero.

Adjunto el "CoritarioFragment" donde tengo la lista y el setOnItemClickListener, despues el "PDF" y despues el "Adaptador"

Primero adjunto la parte donde creo que tengo el error:

```
            Datos obj=(Datos) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            Intent paso = new Intent(getActivity(), PDF.class);
            paso.putExtra("id", (Serializable) obj);
            startActivity(paso);
```

Coritario fragment

public class CoritarioFragment extends Fragment {

```
ListView listaDatos;
ArrayList<Datos> Lista = new ArrayList<>();

Adaptador miadaptador;

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.coritario_fragment, container, false);

    listaDatos = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lstDatos);

    Lista.add(new Datos(1, "asdad"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(2, "asdasd"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(3, "asdasd"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(4, "asdasd"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(5, "ldador"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(6, "asdsad"));
    Lista.add(new Datos(7, "asdas"));


    miadaptador = new Adaptador(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Lista);
    listaDatos.setAdapter(miadaptador);

    listaDatos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Datos obj=(Datos) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);

            Intent paso = new Intent(getActivity(), PDF.class);
            paso.putExtra("id", (Serializable) obj);
            startActivity(paso);
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem((R.id.search_view));
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            miadaptador.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.search_view){
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

PDF

public class PDF extends AppCompatActivity {

```
PDFView mPDFView;
Bundle dato;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf);

    dato = getIntent().getExtras();
    int i = dato.getInt("id");

    mPDFView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
    mPDFView.fromAsset("coritario.pdf").load();
    mPDFView.jumpTo(i);
}
```

CLASE Adaptador

public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

```
Context contexto;
ArrayList<Datos> ListaObjetos;
ArrayList<Datos> ListaObjetosFiltrado;

public Adaptador(Context contexto, ArrayList<Datos> listaObjetos) {
    this.contexto = contexto;
    this.ListaObjetos = listaObjetos;
    this.ListaObjetosFiltrado = listaObjetos;
}

//Retorna cantidad de elementos de la vista
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.ListaObjetos.size();
}

//Retorna objeto puntual de la posicion que indico
@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return this.ListaObjetos.get(i);
}

//Retorna Id del objeto puntual de la posicion que indico
@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return this.ListaObjetos.get(i).getId();
}


//Se ejecuta en cada secuencia de cada hito de la listview
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    //Inyectamos el layout definido dentro de la vista del ListView
    LayoutInflater inflate = LayoutInflater.from(contexto);
    View vista = inflate.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    //Referenciamos el titulo
    TextView titulo = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    titulo.setText(ListaObjetos.get(i).getTitulo().toString());
    return vista;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

            if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                filterResults.count = ListaObjetosFiltrado.size();
                filterResults.values = ListaObjetosFiltrado;
            }

            else{
                String searchStr = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                ArrayList<Datos> resultData = new ArrayList<>();

                for (Datos datos:ListaObjetosFiltrado) {
                    if (datos.getTitulo().toString().toLowerCase().contains(searchStr)){
                        resultData.add(datos);
                    }
                }

                filterResults.count = resultData.size();
                filterResults.values = resultData;
            }

            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            ListaObjetos = (ArrayList<Datos>) results.values;

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
    return filter;
}
```

CLASE Datos

public class Datos {

```
private int posicion;
private String cancion;

public Datos(int i, String cancion) {
    this.posicion = i;
    this.cancion = cancion;
}

public int getId() {
    return this.posicion;
}

public Object getTitulo() {
    return this.cancion;
}
```

}